# How to modify the webchat container of Microsoft Chatbot when using DirectLine

Tags: javascript, botframework, chatbot

I have chatbot where I am using DirectLine to embed the bot in my website. The DirectLine UI looks like a page with white background and I want to modify it to look like the image below or close to it:

[image]

I am following the samples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/SAMPLES.md).

I was able to change the size of the container but I could not change the font or background color of the chat bubbles using the code provided. This is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="webchat" role="main">

</div>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
<!--<script src="webchat.js"></script>-->
<script>
    const styleSetOptions= window.WebChat.createStyleSet({
        bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
        bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)'
    });

    var d1 = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: '<secret token>' })
    var siteDomain = document.URL
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
        {
            directLine: Object.assign(
                {},
                d1,
                {
                    postActivity: activity => {
                        var newActivity = Object.assign({}, activity, { channelData: { "siteDomain": siteDomain } });
                        return d1.postActivity(newActivity);
                    }
                }),
        styleSetOptions 
        },
        document.getElementById('webchat')
    );
</script>
```

This does not work. I have downloaded the CDN `webchat.js`. I have integrated it locally as well by creating my own JS file and linking it in my `HTML` page, it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the **styleSet** you created to **renderWebChat**. Your styleSet is created but is not being used anywhere.

check the below example:

```
 const styleOptions = {
        bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
        bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)'
     };

     window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
        {
           directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
              secret: 'YOUR_BOT_SECRET'
           }),

           // Passing 'styleOptions' when rendering Web Chat
           styleOptions
        },
        document.getElementById('webchat')
     );
```

Comment: I passed the styleOption in the `renderwebchat` but it still does not show me the changes . I have updated the code.

Comment: this is weird, changing styleSetOptions to styleOptions worked. I  did not know this was a special word.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `styleSetOptions` object to `styleOptions` property of `rederWebchat` method i.e.

```
const styleSetOptions= window.WebChat.createStyleSet({
    bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
    bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)'
});

 window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
        {
            directLine: Object.assign(
                {},
                d1,
                {
                    postActivity: activity => {
                        var newActivity = Object.assign({}, activity, { channelData: { 
                      "siteDomain": siteDomain } });
                        return d1.postActivity(newActivity);
                    }
                }),
           styleOptions: styleSetOptions
        },
        document.getElementById('webchat')
    );
```